# Convert jQuery array into string

Tags: jquery

```
$('#btnAfterExtraServicesSelected').die('click').live('click', function () {

   var keys = $('#extras input:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get();
   var pets = $('#pets input:checked').map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get();
   var selectedExtraServices = {};

     for (var i = 0, l = pets.length; i < l; i++) {
         if (pets[i]) {
            var selectedPetKeys = [];
            var name = pets[i] + '-';
            for (var j = 0, k = keys.length; j < k; j++) {
                if (keys[j].substring(0, name.length) == name) {
                     selectedPetKeys.push(keys[j].substr(name.length));
                  }
            }
   selectedExtraServices['extras-' + pets[i]] = (selectedPetKeys.join('+') || '-');
   selectedExtraServices['rextras-' + pets[i]] = null;
                        }
                    }

$('#available-rooms').load('/PetBooking/GetAvailableRoomsForTimesAndDates/', {'selectedExtraServices': selectedExtraServices }, function () {

                    });

                    return false;
                });
```

I need to pass **"selectedExtraServices"** array as a string into **"load()"** method.How could I achieve that ?

**selectedExtraServices** jQuery object is as below:

[image]

Comment: Why exactly does it need to be converted to a String?

Comment: "JSON.stringify", but I'm not sure why you want it as string in the first place.

Comment: @crush b'cos my controller accepts only string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('#available-rooms').load('/PetBooking/GetAvailableRoomsForTimesAndDates/', {'selectedExtraServices': JSON.stringify(selectedExtraServices) }, function () {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

```
{'selectedExtraServices': JSON.stringify(selectedExtraServices )}
```